# Find the longest sub string of a word after concatenation of given words array

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, programming-challenge, recursion

An Array of N words is given. Each word consists of small letters ('a'-'z'). Our goal is to concatenate the words in such a way as to obtain a single word with longest possible substring composed of one particular letter. Find the length of such substring.

Example 1: `words = ["aaba", "aaaa", "bbab"]` -> `maxSubstring=6` of letter `a`, from the concatenated word = `words[1] + words[0] + words[2] = "aaaaaababbab"`

Example 2: `words = ["xxbxx", "xbx", "x"]` -> `maxSubstring=4` of letter `x`, from the concatenated word = `words[0] + words[2] + words[1] = "xxbxxxxbx"`

My current implementation uses brute force:
find all combinations of words, and calculate the max sub-string.
Complexity is \$O(2^n)\$.

I'm looking for better ideas to reduce the time complexity.

```
class candiateCode{
    static Integer max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        String[] arr = new String[N];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextLine();

        }

        findCombi(arr, N, "", new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>());

        System.out.println(max);

    }

    private static void findCombi(String[] arr, int n, String prefix, Map<Integer, Boolean> map) {
        if (n == 0) {
            calculateMaxChar(prefix);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (!map.containsKey(i)) {
                Map<Integer, Boolean> map2 = new HashMap<>(map);
                map2.put(i, true);
                findCombi(arr, n - 1, prefix.concat(arr[i]), map2);
            }

        }
    }

    static void calculateMaxChar(String str) {
        Integer max1 = 1;
        Integer curr = 1;
        char ch = str.charAt(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == ch) {
                curr++;
            } else {
                ch = str.charAt(i);
                curr = 1;
            }
            if (max1 < curr)
                max1 = curr;

        }
        if (max1 > max)
            max = max1;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Think of encapsulation and responsibilities

The `main` method parses the input and uses this piece of code to compute and print the answer:

> ```
> findCombi(arr, N, "", new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>());
>
> System.out.println(max);
> ```

This is ugly in many ways:

- Where does the value of `max` come from? It's a global variable, its value gets set as a side effect of the call to `findCombi`. Try to organize code in a way to avoid side effects.
- What are all those parameters passed to `findCombi`? They are low-level implementation details of `findCombi`. They should not be exposed outside that function. The `main` method shouldn't have to know how the solution is computed. It has the inputs (the array of words), it should pass just that to a function, and get an `int` back as the answer.
- The parameter `N` is redundant, thanks to the `.length` field of arrays in Java.

This is what the snippet should have looked like:

```
int solution = findLongestSubstringCombination(arr);
```

There are no unnecessary parameters, and no side effects needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new logic I came up with 
For each letter, you need to know:

the total length of words consisting entirely of that letter;
the words with the longest and second-longest prefix of that letter; and
the words with the longest and second-longest suffix of that letter
Since each word goes in at most 2 of these groups, determined by the letters it starts and ends with, you can figure this all out in O(N) time
Will post the working snippet shortly